# The background image is not drawn QWidget

Tags: c++, qt, background-image, qwidget

The application has 2 windows. One thing is MainWindow, for which a png image is set as the background through QtStyleSheet. In the class itself, the attributes Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground and Qt::FramelessWindowHint. The second is QWidget, which serves to configure the application. The problem is that in Qt Creator QWidget background image displayed normally, and when you start the application, it is empty. Images used as a background are in the resource file.

(Sorry there is not enough rating to attach images)
Here is an example:

So the background looks like in Qt Creator

[image]

And so when you start the application

[image]

What could be the problem, and how to find its cause?

Comment: Maybe you forgot to add the image to resources? Or used path-specific stylesheet? You coul provide that piece of QSS, which sets the background.

Comment: The image files for the main window and the widget are in the same place in the resource source. I do not think it is connected with the path's.

So I set the styles:

QWidget#Settings{
 background-image: url(:/assets/bgs.png);
}